# jquery: set up child element color from data-attribute

Tags: jquery

Any idea how to make this work?

```
$("div[data-color]").each(function() {
    $(this).children('p').css('color', function () {
        return $(this).data('color')
    });
});
```

and the structure looks like

```
<div data-color="#ff0000"><p>text that needs right color</p></div>
```

Comment: If that's all the relevant markup you are using, then just set DIV color because this propriety is inherited for all descendants  https://jsfiddle.net/5cn0v7mw/

Answer (score 5):

No need of that callback function inside it `this` refers to `p` not the `div`.

```
$("div[data-color]").each(function() {
    $(this).children('p').css('color', $(this).data('color'))
});
```

```js
$("div[data-color]").each(function() {
  $(this).children('p').css('color', $(this).data('color'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-color="#ff0000">
  <p>text that needs right color</p>
</div>
```

---

Or do it with callback like

```
$("div[data-color] > p").css('color',function(){
    return $(this).parent().data('color');
    // or return this.parentNode.dataset.color
});
```

```js
$("div[data-color] > p").css('color', function() {
  return $(this).parent().data('color');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-color="#ff0000">
  <p>text that needs right color</p>
</div>
```

---

With pure JavaScript use **[`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** and **[`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** methods

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div[data-color] > p")).forEach(function(ele) {
  ele.style.color = ele.parentNode.dataset.color;
});
```

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div[data-color] > p")).forEach(function(ele) {
  ele.style.color = ele.parentNode.dataset.color;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-color="#ff0000">
  <p>text that needs right color</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`this` in the `css` callback function refers the `p` element not the `div` element. You can use the second argument of the `each` callback.

```
$("div[data-color]").each(function(i, el) {
    $(this).children('p').css('color', function () {
        return $(el).data('color')
    });
});
```

Another option is:

```
$("div[data-color] > p").css('color', function () {
    return this.parentNode.getAttribute('data-color');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I realised it too. This works but yours too

```
$("div[data-color]").each(function() {
    $(this).find('p').css('color', $(this).attr('data-color'));
});
```